# How to set time in objective C

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I want to set the time in this format.

"2012-09-27 12:03:33+05:30"

Please tell me how to do it.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [NSDateFormatter](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html). 
   Below there is a sample..

```
NSString *dateString=...your_Date_String_Here..   
 NSDateFormatter* fmt = [NSDateFormatter new];
    [fmt setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone]]; 
    [fmt setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
    NSDate* dateFromString = [fmt dateFromString:dateString];
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the [NSDateFormatter](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html) documentation. To to get exactly the output you're looking for you should do:

```
NSDate *date = [NSDate date];
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ssZZZZZ"];
NSLog(@"%@", [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date]);
```